# Mturk Worker ID, completion code and approval

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am trying to solve the following questions in Mturk:

1. Worker ID: I know I can ask the worker for his ID. Is this good practice or can/should I extract the Worker ID from the Referral URL in any other way ?
2. The standard example for an external survey includes a textbox where the worker should input the completion code. I understand that this is a random generated code that **I** have to choose/generate. Or is there an Mturk completion code system ?
3. If the worker enters that code in the textbox (input form). Where will it be stored in Mturk ? In other words, I create a textbox named however I like and amazon takes care of storing this in a csv ? Or am I missing something here ? I would like to know how I can create this textbox and than download a .csv with the assignment id, worker id and that random generated code ?
4. How can I make sure that the worker can only enter that completion code once ? Can i do this with the standard HTML Templates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

(1) Look at this question: [How do you specify the requester's workerID in a mechanical turk HIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916994/how-do-you-specify-the-requesters-workerid-in-a-mechanical-turk-hit/13727863#13727863)

(2) You have to generate the codes. MTurk provides no system for generating these.

(3) That code will be stored in the HIT results, which you will see here: https://requester.mturk.com/manage or via the API. If you use the requester user interface to create the HIT (perhaps working from the survey template), then you should have no problem creating the textbox and extracting the results.

(4) Your last question isn't clear to me. But if you mean to ask how to prevent multiple workers from using the same completion code, that is something you'll have to monitor manually.